# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The multi-part identifier "DM_AG_BIZ.SC.WEBN_X86_BR_BILLDOC.Bill_Doc" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I created this query to fill in the columns `RPS` & `Nota_Fiscal` from table `ZOH_BLS08_IDL.ID_NFUM` & `ZPREFNO` respectively, but I get an "could not be bound" error.

```
insert into [DM_AG_BIZ].[SC].[WEBN_X86_BR_BILLDOC] ([RPS], [Nota_Fiscal])
    select [ID_NFNUM], [ZPREFNO]
    from [DM_AG_IT].[dbo].[ZOH_BLS08_IDL]
    where [DM_AG_BIZ].[SC].[WEBN_X86_BR_BILLDOC].[Bill_Doc] = [DM_AG_IT].[dbo].[ZOH_BLS08_IDL].[BILL_NUM]
```

Comment: Yes, Bill_Doc does not appear to be in your [DM_AG_IT].[dbo].[ZOH_BLS08_IDL] table. It looks like it's in a completely different database altogether if I am understanding your query. You need a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Switch to target database context

USE [DM_AG_BIZ];
GO

-- remove database qualifier on target table
-- Also, remove brackets since not required here

INSERT INTO SC.WEBN_X86_BR_BILLDOC (RPS, Nota_Fiscal)

-- use 2-part column names

SELECT src.ID_NFNUM, src.ZPREFNO

-- alias the source table 

FROM [DM_AG_IT].[dbo].[ZOH_BLS08_IDL] src

-- join to the target table, and alias that as well

JOIN SC.WEBN_X86_BR_BILLDOC tgt
  ON src.Bill_Doc = tgt.BILL_NUM
```